# htaccess fragment problem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I am using some dynamic fragment url encoding thus I have for example a url: localhost/#/home

I wanted to get the htaccess to rewrite this to localhost/home however I am having trouble with this.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: If you want to manipulate such URLs you have to do it via JavaScript on client side.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Fragments are handled client side. They are never sent to the server, so Apache never has access to it. The [approach is broken](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).